# How to alter SVG elements in React js and use Recharts at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, svg, recharts, brush

I'm using `recharts` line chart along with a brush element. I've managed to set a fixed width (length) to the brush traveller by accessing it's SVG element and removing the edges which users use to resize the brush traveller (this is a requirement for my project).

Now, I can access the other elements as well, but cannot alter them. Suggest a method. I tried using `d3` and the output was still unchanged. I want to style the brush traveller like: `height, bg color, border-radius, etc`.